# JAVA Execute powershell script from linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

i want to execute a powershell script from linux using JAVA.

The powershell script is in Windows System. I have to call it from linux system using java bu passing 2 arguments.

is it possible??

thanks

Comment: i want to run a remote powershell script from linux using JAVA.

Comment: okay...upvote for answering your question. but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution...

1. 1st download the FreeSSHD http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download in your windows(server).
   make sure run it as Administrator.

   for setup FreeSSHD follow 
   this URL http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/ 
   after setup you can ssh that windows system from linux or using putty.
2. to execute powershell script from linux to remote windows system using java

```java
package com.sysvana.router.config;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;
public class Test {
static String hostname = "10.1.10.60";
static String username = "administrator";
static String password = "P@ssw0rd"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
conn.connect();
boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword (username, password);
if (isAuthenticated == false){
System.out.println("authentication failed");
} 
System.out.println(isAuthenticated);
Session sess = conn.openSession (); 
sess.execCommand ("powershell C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.ps1"); 
InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler (sess.getStdout ()); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
while (true)
{
String line = br.readLine ();
if (line == null) break;
System.out.println (line);
}
System.out.println ("Exit code" + sess.getExitStatus ());
sess.close ();
conn.close ();
}
}
```

use Ganymed SSH-2 jar http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/